# Missing Right parenthesis but I can't find where

Tags: oracle

Tried making a table in oracle apex and I got the error "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" with this being the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Accessory
(
    AccessoryID VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    AccessoryName VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    Price NUMBER NOT NULL,
    NoInStock NUMBER,
    SuitableFor VARCHAR (20)
    CONSTRAINT Accessory_AccessoryID_pk PRIMARY KEY (AccessoryID)
);
```

I'm really confused because this is very similar code to a table I *just* created and it worked fine

Comment: you missed a comma here SuitableFor VARCHAR (20)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a comma instead like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Accessory
(
    AccessoryID VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    AccessoryName VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    Price NUMBER NOT NULL,
    NoInStock NUMBER,
    SuitableFor VARCHAR (20),
    CONSTRAINT Accessory_AccessoryID_pk PRIMARY KEY (AccessoryID)
);
```

The compiler isn't very helpful in this case.

Comment: also best practice in Oracle to use VARCHAR2.